# Minimalist 3-input XOR gate using CMOS

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, verilog, logic-gates, cmos

As an enthusiastic noob to CMOS I browsed multiple examples of XOR gates using PMOS and NMOS.
I find it hard to find any good examples of **3-input XOR** gates; I found an example of a **4 FET 2-input XOR** that boosts the signal output to full range and thought I'd expand it to 3-input.

The example I found appears to make up for the limitations of PMOS/NMOS by boosting the signal output to the full voltage range when the;

- **PMOS** is disadvantaged by trying to make it pass a **logic 0** signal
- **NMOS** is disadvantaged by trying to make it pass a **logic 1** signal

thusly, where **x_** means **not(x)**;

| ab | a_ | b selects | partial | boost status | boost contribution | strong output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 1 | b==0 -> a | a = weak 0 | CLOSED | b = 0 | 0 |
| 01 | 1 | b==1 -> a_ | a_ = weak 1 | CLOSED | b = 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 | b==0 -> a | a = strong 1 | OPEN | NONE | 1 |
| 11 | 0 | b==1 -> a_ | a_ = strong 0 | OPEN | NONE | 0 |

So I split the problem of a **3-input XOR** into stages using this as a foundation, coming up with (in VERILOG pseudocode);

```
output wire xorabc;
input  wire a, a_, b, b_, c, c_; // ASSUMING DUAL-RAIL INPUTS, ELIMINATING INTERNAL INVERSION
supply1 vdd;
supply0 gnd;
pmos(.out(xnorab ), .in(a_    ), .ctrl (b      ));        // XNOR(a,b) STAGE
nmos(.out(xnorab ), .in(a     ), .ctrl (b      ));

cmos(.out(xnorab ), .in(b_    ), .pcntl(a ), .nctrl(a_)); // SIGNAL BOOST STAGE

pmos(.out(xnorabc), .in(xnorab), .ctrl (c      ));        // XNOR(a,b,c) STAGE
nmos(.out(xnorabc), .in(xnorab), .ctrl (c_     ));
pmos(.out(xorabc ), .in(vdd   ), .ctrl (xnorabc));        // INVERTER AND SIGNAL BOOST STAGE
nmos(.out(xorabc ), .in(gnd   ), .ctrl (xnorabc));
```

giving the following truth-table for a 3-input (a,b,c) XOR gate;

| a | b | c | out |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

as this circuit;

[image]

Am I on the right lines here or have I misunderstood something?
Is it acceptable to eliminate the **cmos()** as the number of FETs passing the signal is small in this case OR do I need another on the second stage producing **xnorabc** before the final inverter 'full-ranging' the signal?

This is for my own project as I'm learning this on my own, and this is not some coursework/homework, so I have nobody else to ask.

Comment: For their significance to arithmetic addition&subtraction, 3-input XOr as well as XNOr and combined circuits are an active area of research. As an "[interested layman](/q/701679/cmos-implementations-of-xor-and-or-xnor)", I find it very difficult to evaluate even the abundance of surveys of implementations.

Comment: I too was surprised to discover this. I thought all this was done and dusted decades ago. Transistors and CMOS ICs, after all, have been around for many years.

Comment: Can you please show a truth table for a 3-input EXOR gate?